# Deploy GWT app into Google Play

Tags: gwt, cordova, google-play, mgwt

I want to deploy my GWT app into Google Play (and maybe App Store in the future). I don't need to use native functions in my app. Just user, password, and I will show one report.

I found mgwt project(http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/). Is mgwt + gwt phonegap the best approach?

Google blog: http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/gwt-support-for-mobile-app-development.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually build mgwt and gwt-phonegap and so its kinda hard for me to say that it is the best way, because I am somewhat biased.

But what I can say is that I know many many developers who have built their applications with mgwt and gwt-phonegap and have put it into the play store and the app store as well. The framework works very nicely. Since I am on the GWT Steering Committee I sure hope that I know how to build GWT frameworks, so mgwt should be doing most of the things just right.

If you are looking for other mgwt developers take a look at our mailing list: https://groups.google.com/group/mgwt and feel free to take a look around at http://www.m-gwt.com